# Rendering DB entry in Expo

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, expo

This is my first go at a expo/react native app, and i have struck trouble,

I am able to `console.log` my firestore db entries fine, but i cant seem to work out how to render them to a view, and to make location cards like the attached image,  [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pdSos.jpg)

Can anyone help?

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { View, Text, StyleSheet } from "react-native";

import firebase from "firebase";
require("firebase/firestore");

const config = {

};

if (!firebase.apps.length) {
  firebase.initializeApp(config);
}

var db = firebase.firestore();

class componentName extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    db.collection("event")
      .get()
      .then((snapshot) => {
        snapshot.docs.forEach((doc) => {
          console.log(doc.data());


        });
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>d</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
export default componentName;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this you need to create a state and need to include your db entries in state, some thing like this:

```
   constructor(props){
       super(props);
       this.state={
           data:[]
       }
   }
```

And set your db entries like this in state data:

```
 componentDidMount() {
    db.collection("event")
      .get()
      .then((snapshot) => {
        this.setState({
        data : snapshot.docs
    })
  }
```

And in view you can render it like this:

```
  return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
      {
        this.state.data.map((item,key) =>{
        return(
        <Text>{item.campusName}</Text>
        <Text>{item.campusAddress}</Text>
        <Text>{item.campusTimings}</Text>
          )
        })
      }
      </View>
    );
```

Hope this helps!